# checkpoint variables used in Spark driver

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-checkpoint

I am streaming data from Kafka , and also maintaining state in my application (by using updateStateByKey) , and so i mandatorily need to checkpoint my data. This is working well.

In addition to data from kafka, i am also using some local variables to keep information like total records,  and some information specific to my application , and this changes according to the data we receive from Kafka.

So i want to persist this information as well, to recover in case of driver failure.
Is there any way to checkpoint this additional data?